# OpenGL vs NupenGL

Tags: visual-studio, opengl, visual-c++, nuget

So, I want to use OpenGL in Visual Studio, using C++. I have seen lots of videos out there, and tutorials, and most of them say that if you want to develop OpenGL programs in Visual Studio, that you should use NupenGL, and install it using NuGet.

I want to know if there are any differences between OpenGL and NupenGL, any incompatibilities, or anything I should know about before using it.

If I shouldn't use NupenGL, what alternatives are there?

Also, if anyone knows, does NupenGL still work? In the NuGet manager this is what it shows: [image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nuget package [nupengl.core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/nupengl.core/) is an easy to use **OpenGL** but it is abandoned so far. Although it could be used, there is nobody to maintain this nuget package. And if you have any other issues about this package, you cannot get any help from others and only yourself.

So the best function is to download the OpenGL from the official website and config it by ourselves. At least someone maintains it officially.

**Assume you use Visual Studio 2019 Community**

**1)** download [GLUT library 3.7](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/glut_downloads.php) and you should click here to get the **zip** file.

[image]

**2)** Close VS, unpack the zip file.

- paste `glut.h` into `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.xx.xxx\include\GL`. If there is not a folder called `GL`, you should create it and then put `glut.h` inside it.
- paste `glut.lib` into `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.xx.xxx\lib\x64`
- paste `glut32.lib` into `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.xx.xxx\lib\x86`
- paste `glut.dll` into `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`
- paste `glut32.dll` into `C:\Windows\System32`

**3)** then restart VS and then create a c++ project, and then right-click on the Project-->Properties--> C/C++ --> Precompiled headers-->change **Precompiled Header** option’s value to `Not Using Precompiled Headers`.

Select **Configuration Properties** --> **Linker** --> **Input**. Now right click on **Additional Dependencies** found on right panel and click **Edit**. Add these:

- opengl32.lib
- glu32.lib
- glut32.lib

Each should be a new line.

**Now**, you can use OpenGL.

Comment: Thanks! This really helped!

Answer (score 0):

From the description of nupengl.core:

"This library adds the various libraries to your project
that are required to build OpenGL applications on both the x86 and x64
architectures. Includes FreeGLUT, GLFW and GLEW."

This sounds like it provides some convenience libraries that you will end up needing in addition to OpenGL. However it also sounds like it will be harder to develop for cross platform.

Plus: "This package has been deprecated as it is legacy and is no longer maintained.
" https://www.nuget.org/packages/nupengl.core/

You're better off taking the long route and building/linking all the proper libraries yourself. MSVC versions of the libraries are more likely to already have precompiled binaries too.